# jenkins does not get war properly exploded - giving tomcat start page

Tags: jenkins, installation, hudson

I downloaded latest jenkins.war (1.530) and just exploded it locally. When I go to localhost:8080 I get only apache tomcat start page instead of dashboard.

Am I missing something?

Running on OSX 10.8.2 with java Oracle 1.7.0_17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the context name in the URL, try:

```
localhost:8080/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

> exploded it locally

where exactly ? within tomcats' webapps folder ? If yes, then you have to start tomcat first.
and then visit the url `http://localhost:<port>/<extractionFolderName>` for e.g. `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`

I also use Jenkins and I prefer to use the standalone version of it, that's more manageable, and then one can run jenkins on different port, without worrying about tomcat's webapps, context and memory consumption.

http://jenkins-ci.org/content/thank-you-downloading-os-x-installer - here you can find the OS X installer.